# Expo-image-picker react native cannot access photo gallery directly on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm using expo-image-picker and it seems like we cannot pick image directly from photo gallery other than android will open phone storage(exp: Downloads folder) and from there we have to locate the photo gallery.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You mean: Expo-image picker does not open in photo gallery directly.

Comment: Anybody having solutions over it ?